# wpf window width size not working when listview scrollbars are removed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2008, listview

I have a WPF project developed with VS 2008 that is using version 3.5 of the .NET framework.  The initial window width is set to 680 and SizeToContent is set to "Width" only.  There are 3 ListView controls that are placed in a grid panel in this window.  The first 2 grids both have one column where the width is specified.  The 3rd ListView control does not specify the width of any column.  When the ListView controls are initially filled with data, the window is properly resized.  If additional data comes in to the 3rd ListView, then the window shrinks or grows the width appropriately.  However, if the 1st or 2nd ListView container grows or shrinks - especially if the scrollbars are removed by increasing the window size vertically, then the width of the window is not correctly updated.  Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can get the window to resize properly when the 2nd and 3rd ListView controls are updated?

Here is my XAML code for the window and ListView controls:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AP2"
        x:Class="AP2.MainWindow"
        x:Name="LobbyWindow"
        Title="Lobby"
        Height="480"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        SizeToContent="Width"
        MinWidth="680"
        MinHeight="480"
        SizeChanged="LobbyWindow_SizeChanged"
        Loaded="LobbyWindow_Loaded"
        Closing="LobbyWindow_Closing"
        StateChanged="LobbyWindow_StateChanged">
  <Window.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                         StartPoint="0.5,0">
      <GradientStop Color="#FF434D7A"
                    Offset="0" />
      <GradientStop Color="#FF180CFA"
                    Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Window.Background>

  ...

  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="0.064*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="0.936*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Define the selected table label. -->
    <Label x:Name="SelTableLabel"
           Margin="1,-5,0,0"
           Content="Table"
           FontSize="11"
           Foreground="#FF000000"
           Background="#FFFFFFFF"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="2"
           FontFamily="Georgia"
           FontWeight="Bold"
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />

    <ListView x:Name="ListView1"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingListViewItemStyle}"
              AlternationCount="2"
              SelectionChanged="ListView1_SelectionChanged"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="0"
              SelectionMode="Multiple"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=LobbyWindow, Path=ListCollection1}">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Game}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Game"
                                  FontWeight="Bold" />
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Stakes}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Stakes"
                                  FontWeight="Bold" />
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn Width="30"
                          DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Seats}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Seats"
                                  FontWeight="Bold" />
          </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <ListView x:Name="ListView2"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingListViewItemStyle}"
              AlternationCount="2"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="1"
              SelectionChanged="ListView2_SelectionChanged"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=LobbyWindow, Path=ListCollection2}">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Width="90"
                          x:Name="TableName"
                          DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TableName}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Table"
                                  Width="90"
                                  FontWeight="Bold"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Stakes}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Stakes"
                                  FontWeight="Bold" />
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NumPlayers}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Players"
                                  FontWeight="Bold" />
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Speed}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Speed"
                                  FontWeight="Bold" />
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HandsPerHour}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="H/Hr"
                                  FontWeight="Bold" />
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AvgPotSize}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Avg Pot"
                                  FontWeight="Bold" />
          </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <ListView x:Name="ListView3"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingListViewItemStyle}"
              AlternationCount="2"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="2"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=LobbyWindow, Path=ListCollection3}">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Player}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Player"
                                  FontWeight="Bold" />
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding City}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="City"
                                  FontWeight="Bold" />
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Chips}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Chips"
                                  FontWeight="Bold" />
          </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried making all three Columdefinition's Width set to Auto instead of * in the Grid.

Comment: Just tried that.  Tried a little experiment and set one of the columns in ListView2 to a long string after it has been initialized and displayed.  It correctly resizes both the control & window when the Width is set to "*".  It does not set the column width correctly when it is set to Auto.  It appears that the only time it fails to set the window width correctly is when it gets rid of the vertical scroll bars.

Comment: By the way, when the vertical scroll bar goes away (from manually increasing the length of the window), the ListView control resizes and it can be seen that the space it was reduced by was exactly the amount occupied by the vertical scroll bar.